# Quartz scheduled jobs failing without showing anything in scheduler logs

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I am using Quartz scheduler to execute jobs. But while trying to schedule jobs for a future time, the jobs get triggered at the right time and immediately goes to failed state without displaying anything in the scheduler logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could not find the root cause for this. But the issue was solved by pointing  to a freshly created Quartz database.

The reason could be that the database might have got corrupted in some way.